# Removing jdk 11 to jdk 8

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk

I have an ubuntu VM, where i by accident installed jdk 11, but i wanted to install jdk 8, and then set the enviroment variable like this.

```
#in the .bashrc file if want to add the following lines
export JAVA_HOME=~/java/jdk1.8.0_161
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export SPTARGET=sandbox
```

the problem is that i did not install the jdk, i did it directly from the command line

`sudo apt install default-jre`

and whenever i check the version with

`$ java -version`
outputs:
`openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16`

does anybody know how i can remove this java version, and then add the java jdk environment variable manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know how :)

#### Uninstall Java first (choose one of these three) :

you can type the following into your terminal :

```
sudo apt purge default-jre
```

if this is not a removable package (although it should be since that's what you installed) then run this instead :

```
sudo apt purge openjdk*
```

if this is **still** not it then this must be it :

```
sudo apt purge oracle-java*
```

#### Then reinstall the Java version you want :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```

there java 8 jdk is now installed.

it now no longer possible (at all, to my knowledge, please correct me if not) to install oracle's version of java 8 (and especially not 9) jdk on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
Select java version you want then check `java -version` again.